# Elegant way to disperse values of array on a boolean mask

Tags: javascript

Say I have an array of values I got from this dates interval `[10/10/2018 - 20/10/2018]`. Some days have values attached like temperature; Other's don't. 
A Boolean mask of presence of value is like `[1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0]`.
and temperature measures are like `[10, 12, 9]`.

What would be an elegant way to disperse values based on mask to get all date measures excepting nulls (-1, null, ...)

result:

```
[10,-1,-1,-1,12,-1,-1,9,-1,-1]
```

Edit: for sake of showing effort. I came up with this:

```
missing_mask.map(function(m) {
    if (m == 1)
        return values.reverse().pop();
    else
        return 0;
})
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit ? Its not very clear what is your input and what is the aim.

Comment: You could use [`shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) instead of `reverse().pop()`. Other than that... what's wrong with your solution? It looks "elegant enough" to me...

Comment: So nice the shift, as for how much elegant is my code, I meant probably less code, maybe Boolean operands instead of conditions, or element wise filter somehow. all are assumptions in my head of possibly better code.

Comment: is it allowed ro mutate `vlaues`?

Comment: yes, @NinaScholz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map `mask` and take either an increasing index of `measures` or `-1`.

```js
var mask = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    measures = [10, 12, 9],
    result = mask.map((i => b => b ? measures[i++] : -1)(0));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES5

```js
var mask = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    measures = [10, 12, 9],
    result = mask.map(function (i) {
        return function (b) {
            return b
                ? measures[i++]
                : -1;
        };
    }(0));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES5 with shifting values

```js
var mask = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    measures = [10, 12, 9],
    result = mask.map(function (b) {
        return b
            ? measures.shift()
            : -1;
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: so nice, I would save this snippet, except I'm bound to javascript ecma 5 spec.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.forEach()` as `forEach()` will loop over to the arry and change the element by reference. Note the `tempMeasure` array. It holds the temperature measure values so that those values can be masked with `1`.

```js
var arr = [10, -1, -1, -1, 12, -1, -1, 9, -1, -1];
var tempMeasure = [10, 12, 9];
var i=0;
arr.forEach(function(item, index) {
  if (tempMeasure.indexOf(item) !== -1) {
    arr[index] = tempMeasure[i];
    i++;
  }
});
console.log(arr);
```